# Magento 2 - Add external scripts from CDN

Tags: magento2, bootstrap4

**I try to load all required scripts for bootstrap 4 like seen on** [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp#div-gpt-ad-1493883843099-0)

**app\design\frontend\company\base\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_menu">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_menu</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> But if I inspect the source code of my site, then I see this:

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/version1573136151/frontend/hausfux/base/de_DE/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/version1573136151/frontend/hausfux/base/de_DE/https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/version1573136151/frontend/hausfux/base/de_DE/https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `src_type="url"` to each `link` element in your `head`

[Check it out in the devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css)

Answer (score 0):

Now, it's also need to configure CSP to whitelist CDN that we will use. Refer to https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/

So the flow will be:

**Step 1**: Register CDN script to `.xml` file. Don't forget the `src_type="url"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> src_type="url"</script>
    </head>
</page>
```

**Step 2**: Configure CSP whitelist. Create `etc/csp_whitelist.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="maxcdn-bootstrapcdn" type="host">https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest Way to use CDN in Magento**

In default.xml path:
**app\design\frontend\company\base\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_menu">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_menu</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create new File path:
**app\design\frontend\company\base\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" src_type="url"></script>
        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" src_type="url"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url"></script>
    </head>
</page>
```